# show objects from my JSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-api, hide, show

I am trying to get my JSON objects to display on a page.

I have the objects in this url

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=myID&key=mykey
```

a sample of the data from the url, that looks like

```
{
  "aspects" : [
    {
      "rating" : 3,
      "type" : "overall"
    }
  ],
  "author_name" : "myname",
  "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/33/reviews",
  "language" : "en",
  "profile_photo_url" : "//lh6.googleusercontent.com/-1GIrDoa_C6g/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAKQ/35IHzHRpoFw/photo.jpg",
   "rating" : 5,
   "relative_time_description" : "a month ago",
   "text" : "text text text.",
   "time" : 1477328845
 },
```

I am trying to display the data on my page I have tried

```
 <body>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
  var requestURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json";

$.getJSONP(requestURL, {
placeid: '232323-bjU891A',
key: '23232-mg'
}, 

function(resultingData) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        resultingData.author_name + "<br />" +
        resultingData.author_url + "<br />" +
        resultingData.language;
}
  </script>

</body>
```

But can not print out the data, please help

Comment: Nothing is ever getting assigned to `text`.

Comment: Ive updated my code

Comment: For one, the method `getJSONP` doesn't exist: http://api.jquery.com/?s=getJSONP . There are also syntax errors in your code. Look at your browser's console to see the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You page needs to make an ajax call to retrieve the JSON data from the API

The simplest way to do this is using the jQuery [function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) `$.getJSON()`

```
var obj;
$.getJSON(requestURL, function(data) {

    // the variable 'data' now contains the JSON response
    obj = data;

}
```

Comment: so keep var requestURL  = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=myID&key=mykey"; then have yor code and then "data" now has the object in ?

Comment: needs to be `JSONP` as it is a cross-domain request

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use simple JSON Http Request  as in http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_http.asp. In this case you don't need attaching jQuery to your project. XMLHttpRequest is a part of Java Script:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var requestURL  = yourUrl;

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status ==  200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        myFunction(data);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", requestURL, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

and then:

```
function myFunction(data) {
    //your code that cares about data from the requestURL
}
```